# Johnny Five Over Bluetooth Connection Issue

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, arduino, arduino-uno, johnny-five

I want to run commands from my computer to an Arduino using JS/Johnny-Five, wirelessly.
I have an Uno and an HC-05. I set the HC-05 up per the instructions [in this URL](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Johnny-Five-and-HC-05-Bluetooth-Serial-Port-Module). I can pair my computer to it and I have uploaded StandardFirmata to the Uno.
But it seems to time out when I try to communicate with it.

When I type, through NodeJS command line

```
> var five = require("johnny-five");
> var board = new five.Board({repl: false, port:'/dev/cu.ailaGduino-DevB'})
```

I get:

```
1480635008609 Connected /dev/cu.ailaGduino-DevB  
undefined
> 1480635018633 Device or Firmware Error A timeout occurred while connecting to the Board. 

Please check that you've properly flashed the board with the correct firmware.
See: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Getting-Started#trouble-shooting
```

It later mentions Timer.listOnTimeout as part of the error call stack.

The Arduino IDE lists that specific device when paired, I guess that's why it says "Connected".

When I try the same command again, I get

```
> var board = new five.Board({port:'/dev/cu.ailaGduino-DevB'})
1480635041136 Connected /dev/cu.ailaGduino-DevB  
undefined
> 1480635041138 Error Error Resource temporarily unavailable Cannot lock port
```

It was fine through USB.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this bit is wrong as your addressing a locally connected device rather than a wifi connected device.

```
var board = new five.Board({port:'/dev/cu.ailaGduino-DevB'})
```

[This tut](https://diyprojects.io/connecting-esp8266-blynk-johnny-five-firmata-wifi/#.XhWxGUf7SUk) suggests you need to connect to the board in a different fasion.

```
var EtherPortClient = require("etherport-client").EtherPortClient;
var board = new five.Board({
port: new EtherPortClient({
   host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",  // IP ESP8266
   port: 3030                
}),
timeout: 10000,
repl: false
});
```

Comment: the tutorial you linked talks about connecting via Ethernet, however, I am looking for connecting to johnny-five for the bluetooth pairing.
Do you have suggestions on how we can have johnny-five interact over Bluetooth?

Comment: ah my bad, i assumed wirelessly as in wifi.

Comment: the only thing i can think of would be to check bluetooth speed see it mentioned here. https://pofay.github.io/2018/11/08/setup-wireless-tethering-for-johnny-five-in-arduino-using-hc05-BT.html

" Cannot lock port" i think that would likely be related to attempting multiple connections at the same time.

Sorry, don't know much more than that.

Comment: you might try this chat channel as well. https://gitter.im/rwaldron/johnny-five